# Google Apis that require an api key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, api-key

In addition to google maps Apis, are there other Google Could Apis that require the usage of an API key? And if so, is it the same key for all Google cloud Apis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are still few Google AI API that accept the API keys, in their older version. The newer version has abandoned the API keys, because [it's not secure, and you can bet on it for the future](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/when-why-api-key).

When you use an API key, you don't identify a person but a project. On this project, you need to have the API activated (if you use a API key for Google Maps and the API isn't activated on the project, it won't work).

In addition, you can restrict the usage of the API key. You can [allow it on one or several APIs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#adding_application_restrictions).

Finally, you can [restrict the API key usage according to the request origine](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#adding_http_restrictions) (control the HTTP host).

Comment: OK. So if you have an API key, you can use it for both Maps APIs and AI APIs?  Or should you create a different API key for each type of API?

Comment: It depends! If it's the same application, yes you can use the same and grant the 2 APIs that you want to use. If it's 2 different apps, it's better to have different keys

Comment: Okay. Merci Guillaume !